# Confusion about Pytorch `torch.split` documentation

Tags: python, split, pytorch

When I view the explanation of the function [`torch.split`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.split.html) in PyTorch, I find it difficult for me to read as a non-English-speaker:

> **`torch.split(tensor, split_size_or_sections, dim=0)`**
>
> [...]
>
> If `split_size_or_sections` is a list, then `tensor` will be split
> into `len(split_size_or_sections)` chunks with sizes in `dim` according
> to `split_size_or_sections`.

Does "with sizes in `dim`" mean "with sizes in `split_size_or_sections` along the dimension `dim`"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry - your English is fine, that line is a bit confusing.

Yes you're correct. It means if you pass a list e.g. `split_size_or_sections=[1,2,4,5]` it will split the tensor into `len([1,2,4,5])` chunks (with the splits happening across `dim`), and each chunk will be of length `1`, `2`, `4`, `5` respectively.

This implicitly assumes that `sum([1,2,4,5])` equals the size of `dim`, and will return an error if not.